# Api gateway for a microservice with multi controller

Tags: spring-boot, api-gateway

I have a microservice with 2 controller is UserController and AdminController, when i configure in api-gateway like that:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=http://localhost:9001
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/api/v1/user/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[1]=Path=/api/v1/admin/**
```

and return 404 error when i use url with http://localhost:8080

please give me solution, thanks